# Is there anything called Execute Non Scalar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Is there anything called ExecuteNonScalar ? in any of the programming language.

Comment: Google says what? What about similar recommendations? -1 due to no prior research demonstrated.

Comment: (There appear to be several "examples" of code mentioning `ExecuteNonScalar` floating about on google .. most seem wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But there is ExecuteNonQuery, and ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a method called "ExecuteScalar" in .NET. It basically returns the first column of first resultant row.

For more info and example you may check this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)